# A dot in the middle of the sentence

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

I want to ask for your advice. Is it correct to put a dot in the middle of the sentence after the name of a book or a document? Or shall I put the name of a book in quotation marks?

For example:

This is an abridged version of the brochure **Progressive Fuel Distribution to Service Station Networks.** intended for representatives of fuel retail or fuel transport companies interested in strategies that enhance fuel distribution productivity to their service station networks.

Comment: Perhaps the titles of a few books actually include a "." in them.  But that would be very rare.

Comment: Is this the only example you have? Most titles of books, papers, etc do not have periods.

Comment: (1) *The day that Mr. and Mrs. Smith went to town was noteworthy.* (2) *The counter is 16 in. deep.*

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen anyone use a dot that way before, and I've never seen a style guide saying that it's acceptable to use a dot that way.

Just use quotation marks:

> This is an abridged version of the brochure "Progressive Fuel Distribution to Service Station Networks" intended for representatives of fuel retail or fuel transport companies interested in strategies that enhance fuel distribution productivity to their service station networks.

The only exception is in the very rare case where the name *contains* a period. For example, there is a band called "fun."—with a period at the end. So it would be fine to write:

> I like listening to music by fun. while riding the bus.

Comment: Another option is to use *italics*.

Comment: Although you could also use Wikipedia's convention and omit fun's period. But that wouldn't be very fun.